# Not able to send email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have email with AMPScript and data extension. I have email validated, send preview for all records in my DE for the email without any error.

When I send email Guided Send or through journey builder I don't see any error but I don't receive  email and can not see any activity in tracking for journey and test sends.

Any help please?

Comment: What's the status of the subscriber?

Comment: Does exist in All subscriber list

Comment: That's not what I asked.  Is the subscriber unsubscribed?

Comment: No they are not